# Modify nested for loop to create multiple xml files based on xml tags

Tags: java, xml, csv

I have some data that I am getting from an excel file (CSV). For each row in the excel file I want to generate a different xml file.

The function I wrote takes in a string of headers and an array list from the CSV file and a file name. I thinking that in my for loop that loops through the strings from CSV file. I need to create a statement that can create multiple xml files based on the number of rows in the excel file or based on the xml tags and then I need to modify that chain in my main method. I need some guidance on how to create that statement. Attatched below is my in.csv File.
Each file once split should be named descriptor_pdx01.xml, descriptor_pdx02.xml, descriptor_pdx03.xml ...... etc.

Also here is the content of the in.csv file.

```
TESTCLIENT_2017_09_30    pdx01   Carcinosarcoma      C34448   M     12
TESTCLIENT_2017_09_30    pdx02   Esophageal carcinoma C4025     
TESTCLIENT_2017_09_30    pdx03   Esophageal carcinoma   C4025       45
TESTCLIENT_2017_09_30    pdx04   Carcinosarcoma       C34448    F   
TESTCLIENT_2017_09_30    pdx05   Esophageal carcinoma    C4025  F   60
TESTCLIENT_2017_09_30    pdx06   Esophageal carcinoma    C4025  F   66
TESTCLIENT_2017_09_30    pdx07   Carcinosarcoma       C34448    M    70
```

[My in.csv File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ali4x.png)

My main method and wrtietoXml method are pasted below Let me know if you have any ideas

```
   import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class CsvToXml {





    public static void main (String Args[]){

        //This is hard coded, in a future version I would consider stripping this from a command-line arg.
        BufferedReader bufferedCsvFile = HelperMethods.getCsvFileBuffer("/Users/edgarjohnson/eclipse-workspace/CsvToXml/in.csv");


        ArrayList<String> csvFileStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
        HelperMethods.readCsvToStrings(csvFileStrings, bufferedCsvFile);


        String[] columnHeaders = HelperMethods.setHeaders(csvFileStrings);
        csvFileStrings.remove(0); // Remove headers from the csvStrings Arraylist
        HelperMethods.writeXmlFile(columnHeaders, csvFileStrings, "xmlOutput.xml");
    }
}
 public static void writeXmlFile(String[] headers, ArrayList <String> stringsFromCsv, String fileName){
        try {
            BufferedWriter buffWrite = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName));
            buffWrite.write("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\r\n");
            buffWrite.write("<patient>\r\n");

            //String array that is the same size is that of the string from csv from line 66-69 

            //For each string in the csv file

            for(String s:stringsFromCsv){

                buffWrite.write("\t<person>\r\n");

                //Split the line into an array of strings
                String fields[] = s.split(",");

                //For each item in that array of strings
                for(int i=0; i<fields.length; i++){
                    //Define a String and keep on adding to that string using field element array, String should be outside for loopLol

                    //Write the corresponding header to the file, as well as the value from the array 'fields'
                    buffWrite.write("\t\t<" + headers[i] +">"+ fields[i] + "</" + headers[i] +">\n");
                }
                buffWrite.write("\t</person>\n");
            }
            buffWrite.write("</people>");
            buffWrite.close();
        }

        catch (IOException ioe){ System.err.println("Error while writing to xml file in writeXmlFile: "); ioe.printStackTrace();
        }



    }
```

Comment: Could you please post your in.csv file? The import statements in your CsvToXml file would be helpful as well to be able to find the needed dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for responding and I am going to do it now

Comment: The dependecies I use for my writeXmlFile method are  import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.FileWriter;

Comment: Very good Edgar. Could you also post the content of the in.csv file?

Comment: Just did It and I appreciate your help

Comment: Thanks for that, but I see your code pulling out the first row of data as column names, yet the CSV data you posted has no header row that looks like column names. Also, what you posted looks like a tab-delimited file, not a CSV file.

Comment: Yes I tried to post the CSV file but my reputation wont allow me too. So I had to post the data from the excel file as a code block instead and use tab to make it more readable.

Comment: Okay, understood. What about the headers (column names)?